# Что будет если будет поступать много GET запросов с одного сайта на другой?

Tags: php, reactjs

Есть один старый,но популярный сайт объявлений и есть идея написать для него трекер ,который будет отправлять GET запрос ,анализировать html на предмет появления новой публикации интересующей тебя.В случае появления будет оповещать КОНКРЕТНОГО ЮЗЕРА по имейлу или смс с сылкой на конкретный новый пост.

Хочу такое сделать,как лично образовательный проект. Но мало знаю о нагрузках.

Так вот вопрос если таких запросов будет много и с таймаутом в 15 секунд,какие подводные камни,что учитывать, и не станет ли сайт с защитой тупо блокировать запросы с моего сайта или как-то их ограничивать.

Comment: Слишком много неизвестных. Много - это сколько? 1 в год, 10 в час, 100 в минуту, 1000 в секунду? Что такое "много"? Дальше - все зависит от защиты самого сайта. Вы можете нарваться на rate-limit, и получать ошибку при переполнении. Вас (а вернее ваш ip) может забанить какой-то anti-ddos guard. Как на всегда, так и на какое-то время. А может никакой защиты и нет и вы просто положите сайт. В общем конкретного ответа при этих условиях вам никто не даст.

Comment: Ну естественно никто не ответить,что у них там за защита и rate-limit. Ну а допустим могу ли я как-то протестировать,чтобы у меня были какие-то данные от которых можно отталкиваться?

Comment: Да, почему нет. Воспользуйтесь vps какой дешевой или прокси и попробуйте. Тут, увы, только опытным путем.